# Override property in nested typescript interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a typescript interface like so:

```
interface DataSku {
  fields: {
    sku: string;
  }
}

interface PostProduct {
  fields: {
    title: string;
    skus: DataSku[];
  }
}
```

Now I want to extend the `Product` interface so that each object in the `skus` array has an extra field. So I tried this:

```
interface Sku extends DataSku {
  stripe: Stripe.skus.ISku;
}

interface Product extends PostProduct {
  fields: PostProduct['fields'] & {
    skus: Sku[];
  }
}
```

In my code, I try a loop like so:

```
(product as Product).fields.skus.forEach(sku => console.log(sku.stripe));
```

This throws the following Typescript error:

```
Property 'stripe' does not exist on type 'DataSku'.
```

Have I extended the interface wrong? The console does output my stripe object as expected, so it's just Typescript that isn't happy with the definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A much more elegant (and working) approach for this would be to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Update `PostProduct` with a generic parameter that's used for the type of `fields.skus`:

```js
interface PostProduct<T extends DataSku = DataSku> {
  fields: {
    title: string;
    skus: T[];
  }
}
```

`T extends DataSku` means the type has to be a subtype of `DataSku`. And we can even set a default value for `T` so `PostProduct` can also be used without having to specify the generic parameter.

Now, for `Product` we just have to pass `Sku` as generic parameter:

```js
interface Product extends PostProduct<Sku> {}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAygawK7IDeAUMsjMBADYAmAzgFxGlnJ35N1hSgDmA3CwC+xEcVCRYiFAAUA9lxlQ5NPAjAAeACrIIAD0gh6aDNnzIAvCcy48APmZkK1ekxKtkYYGCoRO3PkEPdjxGZC0AbQBdIOQRMQloeCRkW10DCCM6azMCdzYAgAc-ZBA8AFsAI2hBBPAk6WQlFTUwdMNjeUVlVXUNWwdCMV82wp7WgEImZt6wQWIxlvUAOmdaOmWQjZg5KABRRAALAAoQywcEORA6OV9lqjleU-xNoogASnf+IA)

---

That said, if you want to it without generics and without modifying `DataSku` and `PostProduct`. You could do this:

```js
interface Product extends PostProduct {
  fields: Omit<PostProduct['fields'], 'skus'> & {
    skus: Sku[];
  }
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAygawK7IDeAUMsjMBADYAmAzgFxGlnJ35N1hSgDmA3CwC+xEcVCRYiFAAUA9lxlQ5NPAjDMyFavSYlWyMMDBUInbn0EH2eRmgzZ8AbQC6V5CLETo8JMlwEEAAekCD09pgBmmwWAA5myCB4ALYARtCCXuA+0shKKmoawaHh8orKqurR2rR2APLJxgA8ZWD5lWBOAOQ19F0uADTIXTZ0XQB8yABk0WSjTAGu7p7ExKYasRWFAIRM7YWCxJsF6gB0vXSno+dyUACiiAAWABQ2yAC8kwhyIHRypqcqHJeK98Fc4hAAJSQ-hAA)

Comment: Yes I see what you're saying. Is this the only way to achieve this though? Ideally I don't want to mess around with my original `DataSku` and `PostProduct` interfaces.

Comment: It's definitely possible, just not as elegant... See the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect! Both solutions worked. To keep my linter happy on your first solution I had to do this: `type Product = PostProduct<Sku>;` to avoid declaring an empty interface.